# How update DataGrid.ItemsSource without freezes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i try to update DataGrid.ItemsSource without freezes

if have:

```
public static DataTable DataTableAccounts { get; set; }
```

Which i get from DataBase (SQLite)

To display this data in the program, I write

```
DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = DataTableAccounts.DefaultView;
```

After changing the data in the **DataTableAccounts**, i update DataGrid

```
DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = null;
DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = DataTableAccounts.DefaultView;
```

But i do that every 1 sec, because data in **DataTableAccounts** is changing so fast. **And because of this update i get freezes window programm.**

Questions:
How i can update DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource without freezes?

p.s. I try to use (async\aswait)... ItemsSource={Binding} in XAML code... and other. Nothing helped me.

Comment: If it is WPF and if you are using binding, you would not need to refresh the UI manually when the grid is updated; that would be taken care by the bindings. Have you set your column bindings?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler , mb i just can refresh the UI from code? Yes, i set column binding

Comment: One problem I see with the approach is that you will setting the entire item source, if it is 1000s of rows, you will take a perf hit while rendering. With Binding, it will only update property that changes, might give you better perf that way. I didNOT write a sample code to test that though..

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler so if i use Binding in XAML, DataGrid updating only changed cells? Binding work only if i refresh the UI manually, how i do that?

Comment: It's bit elaborate to explain in the comments. This article was helpful to me, hope this helps you in understanding on how to set bindings in WPF data grid. That website is a good resource for understanding WPF concepts. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFDataGrid_2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are working too hard.  You need to simply set the data grid items source to the data table.

DataGridAccounts.ItemsSource = DataTableAccounts;

As the data table changes the grid will update.

Answer (score 0):

Following example run background service every 10 seconds to update GUI. You can modify it as you wish. By running your thread as async task your GUI never get hang.

```
public frm_testform()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    dispatcherTimer_Tick().DoNotAwait();

}

private async Task dispatcherTimer_Tick()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    EventHandler tickHandler = (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    timer.Tick += tickHandler;
    timer.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
       // Run your background service and UI update here
        await tcs.Task;
    }

}
```